# Primes in PHP, elliptic curve

Tags: php, server-side, primes, elliptic-curve

how i can calculate receiving a number K, K return the next prime number greater than 2 ^ 57 + 1 ? some 1 can help me with that ?

Comment: How does the value of `K` correspond to the return value?

Comment: like 5 .. 5 primes numbers greater than 2 ^ 57 + 1

Comment: Google for miller-rabin python implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need prime tester, you can download it [here](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Snippets/Prime-tester-9443.html).